# When I change part of the dataframe to a specific value, a 'SettingWithCopyWarning' appears

Tags: python, pandas

When I run the following code, the result is fine, but I get the following warning:

C:\Users\bain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:194: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

```
rdc = pd.DataFrame(raw_data_cutoff)
rdc.to_csv(file_name + '_cutoff' + '.csv', index=True)

initial_window_size = 11
count = 0
window_size = 0

while count <= 100:
    window_size = initial_window_size + count
    rolling = rdc['distance'].rolling(window_size, center=True)
    rdc['median_window'] = rolling.median()
    rdc['std_window'] = rolling.std()
    rdc['mean_window'] = rolling.mean()
    rdc['cv_window'] = rdc['std_window']/rdc['mean_window'] * 100.0
    count += 5
    if rdc['cv_window'].max() < 20.0:
        print('window size = ', window_size)
        break

rdc = rdc.fillna(0, axis=0)

drop_row = int((window_size - 1) / 2)
initial_median_data = rdc['median_window'].iloc[drop_row:drop_row+10].median()
last_median_data = rdc['median_window'].iloc[-drop_row-10:-drop_row].median()

rdc['median_window'].iloc[:drop_row] = initial_median_data
rdc['median_window'].iloc[-drop_row:] = last_median_data
```

In the last two lines of code did I do something wrong? Let me know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC need change [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) to [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and for position of column `median_window` use [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
pos = rdc.columns.get_loc('median_window')
initial_median_data = rdc.iloc[drop_row:drop_row+10, pos].median()
last_median_data = rdc.iloc[-drop_row-10:-drop_row, pos].median()

rdc.iloc[:drop_row, pos] = initial_median_data
rdc.iloc[-drop_row:, pos] = last_median_data
```

Comment: @InhyeokBaeBI - Last 2 rows was changed, can you check it?

Comment: I solved it using the pos you gave me. I do not understand this part yet, so I think I need to study. Thank you so much.

Comment: @InhyeokBaeBI - I try explain it. `iloc` method working only with positions of index and columns. So if have column name instead column position, need `df.columns.get_loc` for return position of column.

Comment: It was a comprehensible explanation. I am really grateful for your help. Thank you!!